# Vue 3 VuetifyJS Grid System Column Span

Tags: grid, vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I'm having a little trouble with the VuetifyJS grid system and would like to know if anyone can help me out. I have several cards in my grid that each have their own content and one card in particular needs to run across two rows as it displays more content. Is this possible using the VuetifyJS grid system without using `display: grid` CSS?

**Current**
[image]

**Desired**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Emillll123/pen/WNgGGNR)

```
   <script type="text/x-template" id="app-template">
  <v-app class="pa-6">
    <v-container>
    <v-row > 
      <v-col>
         <v-row> 
          <v-col class="bg-black">1</v-col>
          <v-col>
            <v-row class="bg-red">2</v-row>
            <v-row class="bg-blue">3</v-row>
          </v-col>
          <v-col class="bg-grey">4</v-col>
        </v-row>
        <v-row> 
          <v-col class="bg-yellow">5</v-col>
          <v-col class="bg-green">6</v-col>
        </v-row>
     </v-col>
      <v-col class="bg-blue">7</v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
  </v-app>
</script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The grid component uses `display:float` so mixing rows and columns requires an extra level of nesting.

Just note that `display:grid` is a better solution. Because of the extra nesting, the heights between components may not fill height. For example, if the content in the right(green rectangle) are is taller than the left side, the left side might not fill the height. But you would also see that in your other areas (like the two vertical `v-col`s in the first row)

[image]